# Django ORM, parent and child connecting

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-orm

**Django ORM**

G'day all,

Hope everyone is well.

I have two tables I'm looking to join and struggling to join in a particular way.

I could easily join them with SQL but rather I would want to do it using Django.

Models below;

**Child:**

```
    class employee(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mySharePlan_ID = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    payroll_ID = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=155,)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=155,null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    TFN = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    subsidary = models.CharField(max_length=155,null=True, blank=True)
    divison = models.CharField(max_length=155,null=True, blank=True)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=155,null=True, blank=True)
    tax_rate = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    hire_date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    terminiaton_date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    termination_reason = models.CharField(max_length=155, blank=True)
    rehire_date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('client', 'payroll_ID',)

    def __str__(self):
        full_name = "Payroll ID: " + self.payroll_ID + ", " + self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
        return full_name
```

**Parent:**

```
    class offer_eligibility(models.Model): 
    offer = models.ForeignKey(offer,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(employee,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount_offered = models.PositiveBigIntegerField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Any employee can have many offers.

I'm trying to create a view that shows a list of employees who are in a selected offer and if they have any amount_offered.

This requires me to first filter the offer_eligibility by the offer, I have this queryset. (**Note:** I realized i shouldn't be filtering this)

I want to add that queryset onto the employee queryset (filtered by client, easy enough to filter) and where the employee does not exist in the queryset I want amount_offered to be None/null.

Currently I cannot join the parent data onto the child data, I've tried a few different things but in raw SQL this is fairly trivial, so I'm thinking I am clearly not understanding something.

**Edited: SQL below;**

```
SELECT [staff_employee].[id]
      ,[mySharePlan_ID]
      ,[payroll_ID]
      ,[first_name]
      ,[last_name]
      ,[TFN]
      ,[subsidary]
      ,[divison]
      ,[job_title]
      ,[tax_rate]
      ,[hire_date]
      ,[terminiaton_date]
      ,[termination_reason]
      ,[rehire_date]
      ,[client_id]
      ,iif(offer_id != 3, 0, [amount_offered]) /* 3 is the offer PK */

  FROM [ESS_Database].[dbo].[staff_employee] left join [staff_offer_eligibility] on [staff_employee].id = employee_id

  where client_id = 1
```

I feel like I am very close.

I just need to change the value to be F('offer_eligibility__amount_offered') however when i do this I get an error.

"raise FieldError('Cannot resolve expression type, unknown output_field')
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve expression type, unknown output_field"

```
qs = queryset.filter(client=context['selected_client'][1]).annotate(
                amount_offered=Case(
                When( offer_eligibility__offer = self.kwargs['pk'] 
                ,then=Value(0))
                ,default=None)).query
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Comment: Can you include your raw sql query?

Comment: added, I realized I dont need to filter the offer eligibility object more just the extra column if it doesn't equal the offer PK then it needs to be 0/null/None. 

This will show the user the employee is not in the offer meaning they can include them or not. 

The reason i want to use Django ORM to do this is because I want to use django-filters.

Comment: employee.objects.filter(client=clientpk).annotate(somecol=F('offer_eligibility__amount_offered'))

I've got this so far which is close because at least now i'm getting the join the right way. mmm

Comment: got it working in django-tables2 but now I just need to filter the annotation. I'm very close to the answer, once i get it ill post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! after all day trying to work it out.

I feel I have a lot better understanding of how Django writes SQL now.

**Filtering the model queryset**

```
def get_queryset(self): #Filter queryset for client
        queryset = super(FilterView, self).get_queryset()
        context = selected_client(self.request)
        queryset = queryset.filter(client=context['selected_client'][1]).annotate(
                amount_offered=Case(
                When( offer_eligibility__offer = self.kwargs['pk'] 
                ,then=F('offer_eligibility__amount_offered'))
                ,default=None))
        return queryset
```

**My  Django-tables2:**

```
    class offer_eligibility_table(ExportMixin,tables.Table):
    client_name = tables.Column(accessor='client__client_name')
    mySharePlan_ID = tables.Column(accessor='mySharePlan_ID')
    payroll_ID = tables.Column(accessor='payroll_ID')
    first_name = tables.Column(accessor='first_name')
    middle_name = tables.Column(accessor='middle_name')
    last_name = tables.Column(accessor='last_name')
    hire_date = tables.Column(accessor='hire_date')
    amount_offered = tables.Column(accessor='amount_offered')
```

So to walk you through the answer, I first needed to filter on client, then I need to add a column to the original model which was my amount_offered but I only wanted to add the values if the employee was in the offer, as such I needed to use the case function, definitely recommend giving conditional-expressions a read if you are looking at my question and wanting similar help.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/

So I had to change it I ended up annotating a column with the offer ID it they were null or the same offer ID then filtering on that offer ID, if only I could have worked out how to do an inner join. >.>

Comment: This didnt solve the issue.. I now have multiple records of the same employee... how do I annotate without creating duplicate rows if there is more than 1 offer?